# Fetch tag names from XML

Tags: java, xml

I have some XML:

```
<Details>
    <name>sam</name>
    <age>18</age>
</Details>
```

Using the code below, I'm able to read the values values `sam` and `18`. I also need to retrieve the element names `name` and `age`. How do I get it?

My current code:

```
Element root = XMLDocument.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nodelist = root.getChildNodes();
String[] rowdata = new String[2];
for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < nodelist.getLength(); nodeIndex++) { 
  Node node = nodelist.item(nodeIndex);
  for(int elementIndex=0; elementIndex<node.getChildNodes().getLength(); elementIndex++){ 
    rowdata[0] = node.getChildNodes().item(elementIndex).getNodeName().toString();
    rowdata[1] = node.getChildNodes().item(elementIndex).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(rowdata[0] + " - " + rowdata[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: Try to use DOM Parser

Comment: @user3089869 In future, please add that code to your question as I have done. Can you please explain what is wrong with your code? Tell us about any errors and any deviations from expected behaviour.

Comment: my output is #text - sam
             #text - 18. But i want it to be name- sam
                                             age - 18

Comment: Can we directly Fetch Data From XML File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how to print the element names:

```
String xml = "<Details><name>sam</name><age>18</age></Details>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml
    .getBytes("US-ASCII")));

Element root = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nodelist = root.getChildNodes();
String[] rowdata = new String[2];
for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < nodelist.getLength(); nodeIndex++) {
  Node node = nodelist.item(nodeIndex);

  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName()); // Here we can print the element name
  }

  for (int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < node.getChildNodes()
      .getLength(); elementIndex++) {

    Node childNode = node.getChildNodes().item(elementIndex);
    rowdata[0] = childNode.getNodeName().toString();
    rowdata[1] = childNode.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(rowdata[0] + " - " + rowdata[1]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
name
#text - sam
age
#text - 18
```